# Ruby - parse JSON file with nested arrays to ruby hash without data loss

Tags: arrays, json, ruby

I have a `file1.json` with structure like this :

```
[
  {
    "uri": "features/hdp.feature",
    "id": "as-a-user-i-want-to-use-house-detailed-page",
    "keyword": "Feature",
    "name": "As a user I want to use house detailed page",
    "description": "",
    "line": 2,
    "tags": [
      {
        "name": "@hdp",
        "line": 1
      }
    ],
    "elements": [
      {
```

As you can see - it is an array with nested key:value pairs and other arrays. I need to convert it to ruby hash, but when I'm performing `JSON.parse(file1)` - it creates an array (http://prntscr.com/lqio6r) with ruby hashes, arrays and so on. If I'm performing `JSON.parse(file1).reduce Hash.new, :merge or JSON.parse(file1).reduce Hash.new, :update)` - as one of the answers on StackOverflow supposed - the result hash losses about 60% of .json content. Can you please advice on how can I convert json file to ruby hash (without any data losses)?

UPD - not truncated array - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/M1khah/3337507e3ca1544e6098bc726bca90cb/raw/c8262ad753bd0eebf1180e111acd016ffc07d1a5/gistfile1.txt
Hash with hashes - something like this instead of an array with nested hashes

```
{
   {
        "uri": "features/hdp.feature",
        "id": "as-a-user-i-want-to-use-house-detailed-page",
        "keyword": "Feature",
        "name": "As a user I want to use house detailed page",
        "description": "",
        "line": 2,
        "tags": [
          {
            "name": "@hdp",
            "line": 1
          }
        ],
        "elements": [
          {
    }
```

Comment: Well, your structure IS an array. And hashes can't have any duplicate keys (which is probably what you refer to as "data loss"). Post a bigger source array and exactly what hash you're hoping to convert it to.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev well, source array is big, here is a json representation of it (truncated by Gist)- https://gist.github.com/M1khah/3337507e3ca1544e6098bc726bca90cb

Comment: @SergioTulentsevand a desried Hash should be just a hash with hashes which are currently in an array

Comment: Post it too. As it is, I can't really tell what exactly you mean by "just a hash with hashes"

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I've updated the answer to meet your requirements

Comment: Your desired result is not a valid ruby hash. As such, it's impossible to produce.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev good point, ty. I'll think about possible workarounds